# When braking RPM drops and radio cuts off (Sometimes when rolling down the window same happens)

Tags: honda, civic, rpm, power-windows, iac-valve

I have a 2002 Honda Civic, it has been working great for many years until now. I have been having strange things happen:
When I apply the brakes or roll down the window the RPM drops and my radio cuts off.

I have replaced the IAC valve and tested for leaks. I have also cleaned out the throttle body but the problem is still there.
Couple of thing to note: when the car is cold I do not have the above problems, it’s only when the car has been driven for 10-15min when the problems start. RPM drop also is not consistent, sometimes when I brake or roll down the window I do not get above symptoms and sometimes I do. I also do not have any error code and my radio is the original radio, the car has a manual transmission.

Any help at this point will be greatly appreciated.

Z

Comment: This may be related to my question:  https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/55200/how-does-electrical-load-shedding-work-in-an-automobile

Comment: Possibly a fuse or an ignition switch

Answer (score 1):

As all circuits being used are electiral (power windows/brake light switch) i would suggest when it warms up, something loose is expanding and causing shorts which are affecting the running circuit which could be reducing fuel/spark effort